# vim - exit paste mode before `>gv`

Tags: vim

TL;DR I find it cumbersome to get in and out of paste mode to paste stuff from outside vim.  I have `nnoremap <Leader>r :set invpaste paste?<CR>` - but I inevitably forget to exit before I start reformatting what I pasted - which then inserts tabs instead of spaces, so then that has to be cleaned up.

---

I have this now:

```
vmap > >gv
vmap < <gv

set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent smartindent expandtab smarttab hlsearch
```

So I can select multiple lines (shift-v, j, j, j) and then hold shift and press '>' multiple times to indent (two spaces, not tabs).

Problem is if I `:set paste` and paste a bunch of stuff from my paste buffer outside of vim (using cmd-v) I have to manually switch out of pastemode.

I want to just immediately switch out of paste mode as I `(shift-v, j, j, j)`

So, I think I want to modify this:

```
vmap > >gv
```

to automatically `:set nopaste`

I tried a function to no avail:
DOESNT WORK:

```
function! ShiftRight()
  if &paste
    set nopaste
  endif
  normal! >
endfunction

vmap > :call ShiftRight()<CR>gv
```

Another fail:
`vmap > :set nopaste<CR>>gv`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative, more optimal and more idiomatic approach:

1. Get a Vim built with clipboard support if you don't have one.

   I recommend [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases), which comes with both a TUI and a GUI while still being a pretty good macOS citizen.
2. Set the `:help 'clipboard'` option properly.

   On macOS, the registers `@+` and `@*` both point to the system clipboard so you can use either `unnamed` or `unnamedplus`, here:

   ```
   set clipboard^=unnamed
   ```
3. Drop `Cmd+V` and use Vim's native `y`, `p`, etc. You can use `:help [p` or `:help ]p` to put at the correct indentation level.

No need for any of those `:help 'paste'` shenanigans.